# force directed d3 zoom and pan works only on link paths excluding the nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to apply zoom and pan to my force directed layout graph but it only works on the links, the nodes doesn't go with the links and seems to be floating everytime I zoom and pan.

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
.linkDistance(90)
.charge(-1000)
.gravity(.100)
.size([width, height])
.on("tick", tick);

function zoom() {
console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
console.log("transform", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
//vis.attr("transform", transform);
node.attr("transform", transform);
link.attr("transform", transform);
}

function transform(d) {
return "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")";
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
node = svg.selectAll(".node");

var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div") // declare the tooltip div 
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 0);
svg.style("cursor", "move");


function readfile(json) {
root = json;
update();
};

function update() {

var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

// Restart the force layout.
force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

// Update links.
link = link.data(links, function (d) {
    return d.target.id;
});

link.exit().remove();

link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
    return d.target.level;
});

// Update nodes.
node = node.data(nodes, function (d) {
    return d.id;
});

node.exit().remove();

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

var defs = node.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs");

var imgPattern = defs.append("pattern")
    .attr("id", "imgPattern")
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0");

imgPattern.append("image")
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
    return d.image;
});

node.select("circle")
    .style("fill", "url(#imgPattern)");

nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .style("stroke", color)
    .style("stroke-width", 4)
    .style("fill", "url(#imgPattern)")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {

    circlePos = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("left", (circlePos.left + circlePos.width + window.scrollX) + 'px')
        .style("top", (circlePos.top + window.scrollY) + 'px')
        .style("position", "absolute")

    div.html(
        "<div style='position: absolute; border:2px solid red; background-color: yellow; z-index=-1'>" +
        "<div class='container'>" +
        "<div id='wrap'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-3'>" +
        "<div class='g-hover-card'>" +
        "<div class='user-avatar'>" +
        "<img src='" + d.image + "' alt='' style='margin-top:50px;'/>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='info'>" +
        "<div class='description'>" +
        "<font size='5px' color='black'>" + d.name + "</font>" +

        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='bottom'>" +
        "<br/>" +
        "<a id='thisLink' onclick=\"window.open('http://facebook.com/" + d.pid + "');\" >" + "Follow on Facebook" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>")
    $('#thisLink').click(function (e) {
        window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Iconnect/generate_tree";
        window.location.reload();
    });

})
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .each('end', function (d) {
        d3.select(this).html("");
    });
});
div.on("mouseover", function (d) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", .9);
})
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .each('end', function (d) {
        d3.select(this).html("");
    });
});

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
});
}

function tick() {
link.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.source.x;
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d.source.y;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d.target.x;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return d.target.y;
});

node.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});
}

function color(d) {
return d._children ? "#800000" // collapsed package
:
d.children ? "#008000" // expanded package
:
d.parentNode ? "#000000" : "#68228b"; // leaf node
}

 // Toggle children on click
function click(d) {
if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
} else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
}
update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
var nodes = [],
    i = 0;

function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
}

recurse(root);
return nodes;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/aizenRiley/6veayfuh/) of what I have so far done.

How can I implement graph zooming and panning for the nodes to go with the link paths?

and is it possible for the nodes to stick by default I have seen a sample wherein nodes stick but only when it is dragged; because the json data I'm using is dynamic so if there are huge data the graph seems kinda messy because its moving.

Comment: Try to use a container and then call the zoom on him. I had the same issue like you.

Comment: @kwoxer what do you mean? sorry I'm not used to javascript. can you give me an example. Thanks

Comment: Look at my example here. http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/2/ First of all look if that zooming is something you want. And then search for container. The code is really easy, but ask me anything if something is unclear.